# High dimensional latin square

Tags: combinatorics

As we know, latin squares are important objects studied in combinatorial design, I'm wondering whether there are any researches on their high dimension analogs?

Recall that a latin  square is an $n\times n$ metrix with entries in $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, such that every rows and columns contain all the numbers in $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$.

So, we can define a $k$-dimension latin square to be an $\underbrace{n\times n\times \cdots \times n}_{k\text{ times}}$ array $A$ with entries in $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, such that no two entries which lie in the lines parallel to axis have the same value.

Comment: Here's a nice paper: http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/hypercubes.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There's the paper by McKay and Wanless mentioned in a comment above. There's also the following: A Latin square can be identified with an $n\times n\times n$ $0-1$ array in which each axis-parallel line contains a single $1$. This is a high-dimensional analogue of a permutation matrix. Thus, Latin squares may be thought of as high-dimensional permutations. If you Google the term "high-dimensional permutations" you'll find quite a bit.